# How to set CV title margins and alignment in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am writing a resume in Latex using the moderncv class and I want to body of the resume to have different margins than the title. However, when I adjust the margins the title margins also adjust and it doesn't look as good because my name and phone number/email/address are too spaced out. Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv} % version 1.5.1

%\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}  % used in version <= 0.15
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{vwcol} 
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm, footskip=0.4cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
\firstname{First}     % Your name
\lastname{Last}       % Your last name
\phone{xxx-xxx-xxxx}            % Your phone number
\email{email@gmail.com}             % Your email address
\extrainfo{Address}   % Possible extra information e.g. website

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\setlength{\footskip}{52pt} % to avoid warning

\section{\textbf{Experience}}
\cvitem{2018-Present}{\emph{Researcher}, Cool University}
\cvlistitem{\textbf{Doing this, that, and the other}}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know a way to format the margins for the title alone? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please your code snippet to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, a MWE should compile. Also how, exactly, should the title look? It would be easier to help you if you could give more detail as to what you want.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I fixed my MWE that will compile. When you compile it, the first name and last name are very far apart from the address/email/phone number. In the original ```moderncvstyle{classic}``` class they are close together and centered, but when I change the page margins to be able to fit more text across the entire page, they become separated. I want to find a way so that this doesn't happen and they can be close together like in the original (if you remove ```\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm, footskip=0.4cm]{geometry}``` you will see how I want it to look). Thanks!